# Accessibility identifier not persisting in interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, accessibility

In interface builder, I am marking a view in xib file as `accessibility enabled`, and assigning a string identifier.

Once I exit the file this information is lost, not appearing in git diffs.

Tried:

1. Quit Xcode
2. Delete derived data
3. Restarting my mac.
4. Cleaning project
5. Clean build folder

Note: 
The first time I noticed this, I quit Xcode, assigned some identifiers which were recognised by git, and they persisted. 
However, since then this issue keeps appearing and quitting Xcode or any other thing fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If Xcode is not properly saving the accessibility settings of your object in the xib file, you can set the accessibility when you initialize the object by using the following code:

```
.isAccessibilityElement = true
```

Comment: Thank you, we know that option.. but we need an interface builder solution

Answer (score 1):

What helped for me was building and running the project before running the UI Tests.
For some reason they get reverted if you try to do the UI Test directly, they dissappear.

Answer (score 1):

#### Two solutions (Xcode 14.2)

I have an identical issue, which appears to be an Xcode bug.

##### Solution 1: Manually editing the XML

1. Right click the Storyboard file and select 'Open as > Source Code'
2. Find your view
3. Change:
   `<accessibility key="accessibilityConfiguration>` to  `<accessibility key="accessibilityConfiguration, identifier: "any-identifier">`

##### Solution 2: Add a 'User Defined Runtime Attribute'

Adding an `accessbilityIdentifier` as a runtime attribute.

1. Open the right pain in Xcode and select the `Identity Inspector`
2. Click the '+' for adding `User Defined Runtime Attributes`
3. Add "accessibilityIdentifier" as a `KeyPath`
4. Add <'Your identifier'> as a Value